# How to start play audio automaticly on mobyle device?

Tags: audio, mobile, ratchet-2

I  crate audio tag, and use 'autoplay' to start audio. On Descktop work well, but not work on mobile device: ipad, winphon, android 4+...

```
<audio id="myAudio"  onerror="toConvert()" class="full-width"  src="{{ direct_link }}" controls autoplay  onpause="$('#play_ico').show()"   onplaying="$('#play_ico').hide()"></audio>
```

I tried using jquery, js, canplay, canplaythrougt and many other methods from web, but they dont work in mobile and working well on descktop....

How can I start playing audio on mobile device?

I use: goRatchet, Bootstrap  and Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
>   be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
>   autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.
>   This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive
>   until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method
>   is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play
>   button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.

```
This plays the movie: <input type="button" value="Play" onclick="document.myMovie.play()">

This does nothing on iOS: <body onload="document.myMovie.play()">
```

You can ref: [Playing Sounds with the Web Audio API.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH6-SW1)

Comment: How m.youtube.com start play video automaticly?

Comment: @user3080031: Yes, i will show you a demo. You can check it on iphone.
[demo on iphone about playauto](http://bfred-it.github.io/iphone-inline-video/demo/). Hope you can check debug and see attribute video. If failed, you can contact via skype: tungtrum17 , i will help you. good luck.

Comment: I try to play mp3 sound automaticly on my page, and it work if i only start it whit "muted" attribut.

Comment: On Windows Phone 8.1 "autoplay" working well.  On windows phone 10 (al brousers) not work